# Recommendations to implement Service bus or Pubnub

Tags: c#, wpf, azureservicebus, pubnub, servicebus

I am trying to develop a WPF chat application where users can able to chat either personal or in group.Now,I'm trying to achieve something new(atleast in my case) where multiple users are logged
in multiple devices and a user created a group chat(added multiple users who are logged in other devices) then the users should be notified immediately that they are added to a group chat.

Can anyone please suggest me the ways to achieve this.

I've come to know that this can be implemented by using service bus or PubNub,
How can I use pubnub for this can anyone please suggest me the pubnub implementation for this kind of requirement

If I can implement this through service bus which can I choose for the better implementation

1 ".NET Service Bus Queues "

2 "Azure Queue Service "

are any new suggestions to implement this??

Comment: Since it's a chat application , have you considered Azure SignalR service ?  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/signalr-service/

Comment: Azure Service Bus is **not** a good candidate for a chat application.

Comment: There is a lot of resources related to using PubNub for chat (our biggest use case) and we have massive scale chat customers in production. Please look at our site for examples, sample apps, etc. And contact [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) to engage with the right people to get you started on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial for chat with PubNub, C#, and Unity which you can find at [unity.chat](https://unity.chat/). That may be helpful for you because it is using the same language.

There is also an example of basic Pub/Sub with [PubNub in a WPF application](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/c-sharp-desktop-notifications-wpf-mvvm/?devrel_so=recommendations-to-implement-service-bus-or-pubnub) on the PubNub blog.

At the current time there is no specific example of PubNub and chat rooms in a Windows Desktop application. However there is a [best practices playbook for using PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/c-sharp-dot-net-c-sharp/best-practices-playbook?devrel_so=recommendations-to-implement-service-bus-or-pubnub) and also a [Chat Best Practice guide](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-04-28-chat-app-best-practice-guide-with-javascript-sdk/?devrel_so=recommendations-to-implement-service-bus-or-pubnub) PDF at the bottom of this blog post.